# How do I scroll a list item to the top of my page when I click on it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll, focus, scrollview

I'm using jQuery mobile and I have a long unordered list like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" />
<div id="scroller" />
<div class="trans" />
<ul id="thelist" data-corners="false" 
<div class="theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="right">
        <h3>$111.58   -  10/30/2012   -   McDonalds Restaurant  -  Chicago Il</h3>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <a class="green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button">Yes</a>
            <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">Not deductible</a>
            <a class="blue" href="IDontKnow.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">I don't know</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="right">
            <h3>$111.58   -  10/30/2012   -   McDonalds Restaurant  -  Chicago Il</h3>
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a class="green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button">Yes</a>
                <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">No</a>
                <a class="blue" href="IDontKnow.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">I don't know</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="right">
                <h3>$111.58   -  10/30/2012   -   McDonalds Restaurant  -  Chicago Il</h3>
                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <a class="green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button">Yes</a>
                    <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">No</a>
                    <a class="blue" href="IDontKnow.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">I don't know</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, I'm trying to make it so that when I click on any list item, that list item highlights and scrolls to the top of my viewport, just underneath the title.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `$.scrollTo()` plugin and the jQuery UI `highlight` function.

Check this question also, it has a nice solution to scroll to elements: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $("#scroller").css('top','0');
});
```

Comment: That scrolls the browser scroll bar fine, but I have my own scroll bar inside the page that I want to scroll.  I tried `$('a').click(function(){
    $("#scroller").scrollTop(0);
});` but i got nothing.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Ok. I thought you was used auto scroll. Try this `$('a').click(function(){ $("#scroller").css('top','0'); });`